# How to save an element by string name?

Tags: r

I'd like to know how to save an element with `save` function by using the object name.

Here's an example:

```
my_object <- c("1","2")
```

What I'd like to do:

```
save("my_object", file = "my_object.rda")
```

So that the repository have all my elements.rda, and when I load them later, they have their original name.

Thanks!

Comment: Dont use the quote marks: `save(my_object, file = "my_object.rda")`

Answer (score 1):

Most straightforward is use the object without quotes, however if you want to use a variable object name as a string you can do it with `get`. Just a demo, print suits as an example as well as saving your file.

```
my_object <- c("1", "2")

print(my_object)
[1] "1" "2"

print("my_object")
# "my_object"

print(get("my_object"))
# [1] "1" "2"
```

**solution to write your file dynamically**

```
save_me <- "my_object"
obj <- get(save_me)
save(obj, file = paste0(save_me, ".rda"))
```